# Extending a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance, emit

I trying to extend this module: https://github.com/gildean/node-udp-proxy so it has some kind of method for closing the the proxy when I do not need it anymore.  I have tried the following approaches with failure:
1. Trying to extend the code, using inherit.
2. using event emitter to close. 
3. Copy the code and extend the module directly by creating the following code in index.js, but I could not manage to call it from the instantiated object.

```
UdpProxy.prototype.closeClient = function closeClient() {
    var proxy = this;
    //this.close();
    proxy.emit('proxyClose', this.peer);
    this.removeAllListeners();
    delete proxy.connections[senderD];
}
```

I didnt get any approachs to work yet.  I'm a bit of a node.js newbie.  I've been reading different articles about inherit but was unable to get the example to work in my context.

Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `close()` as a method on `this`? Looks like it may actually be a method on `client`. Not 100% positive, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: this.close() gave me an error.  Not sure how to implement your suggestion.  Could you give me anymore details please?  Thx for your reply.  How would I access client from the additional code I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the end.

server._server.close();